# Trouble with jQuery UI accordion (collapsable)

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

Having trouble with jQuery again-- This time, I need a collapsible accordion for my navigation.

When I click on "work" I want the list to open. I'm currently using the same jquery used in the example [here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible).

Right now, I'm just trying to get it to work... But I would like it to default to collapsed so it can be opened. Not sure how to do that part.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bG52W/

The HTML

```
<ul class="accordion">
<li><a href="#"><h1>work</h1></a></li>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#section1"><p class="nav_p">anatomy of type</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2"><p>clash album redesign</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3"><p>"ghost" book jacket</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4"><p>charlie chaplin</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5"><p>design influence</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6"><p>"thrift thoughts" zine</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section7"><p>cigarette card illustration</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section8"><p>"frosty" winecooler packaging</p></a></li>
  </ul>

<li><a href="#"><h1>about</h1></a></li>

<li><a href="#"><h1>contact</h1></a></li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  });
```

Any and all help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bG52W/3/

Even if all your code was right. It would have never worked in the jfiddle. You didn't check jQuery UI on the left.

Other than that your structure was a bit wrong:

> The markup of your accordion container needs pairs of headers and
>   content panels:

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion

```
<div class="accordion">
<h1><a href="#">work</a></h1>
  <div class="nav">
      <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1"><p class="nav_p">anatomy of type</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2"><p>clash album redesign</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3"><p>"ghost" book jacket</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4"><p>charlie chaplin</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5"><p>design influence</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6"><p>"thrift thoughts" zine</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section7"><p>cigarette card illustration</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section8"><p>"frosty" winecooler packaging</p></a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
<h1><a href="#">about</a></h1>
  <div><a href="#"><h1>about</h1></a></div>
<h1><a href="#">contact</a></h1>
  <div><a href="#"><h1>contact</h1></a></div>
</div>
```

Also like the voice said, your selector was wrong.

```
$(function () {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your selector $( "#accordion" ) is wrong. Should be $( ".accordion" )

Comment: Is there a way to make it so it defaults to being collapsed?

Comment: @Brooke http://jsfiddle.net/hellomynameisluc/bG52W/4/ add "active: false" option to the accordion function